# Install Spartacus with a list of features

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I try to install spartacus by defining a list of features..I'm using the following command
`

```
ng add @spartacus/schematics@latest \
--skip-confirmation \
--baseUrl https://localhost:9002/ \
--baseSite=powertools-spa \
--currency=usd \
--language=en \
--ssr \
--interactive=false \
--features=ASM \
--features=Import-Export \
--features=Saved-Cart \
--features=Quick-Order \
#--features=WishList \
--features=Checkout \
#--features=Checkout-B2B \
#--features=Cart \
#--features=Checkout-Scheduled-Replenishment \
--features=Order \
--features=Administration \
--features=Order-Approval \
--features=Bulk-Pricing \
--features=Image-Zoom \
--features=Product-Variants \
--features=Qualtrics \
--features=SmartEdit \
--features=Store-Finder \
--features=Account \
--features=Profile
```

But I receive the following error message:
 `Data path "/features/4" must be equal to one of the allowed values. Allowed values are: "ASM", "Import-Export", "Saved-Cart", "Quick-Order", "CDC", "CDS", "Checkout", "Order", "Digital-Payments", "EPD-Visualization", "Administration", "Order-Approval", "Bulk-Pricing", "Image-Zoom", "Product-Variants", "VC-Configurator", "Textfield-Configurator", "CPQ-Configurator", "Qualtrics", "SmartEdit", "Store-Finder", "Personalization", "TMS-GTM", "TMS-AEPL", "Account", "Profile"`.My question would be the Wishlist and the Checkout-B2B or Cart why are not in the allowed values list?

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide some guide on this:
The valid values are defined inside
`spartacus/projects/schematics/src/add-spartacus/schema.json`

```
    "features": {
      "type": "array",
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "enum": [
          "ASM",
          "Saved-Cart",
          "Quick-Order",
          "CDC",
          "CDS",
          "Checkout",
          "Digital-Payments",
          "Administration",
          "Order-Approval",
          "Bulk-Pricing",
          "Product-Variants",
          "VC-Configurator",
          "Textfield-Configurator",
          "CPQ-Configurator",
          "Qualtrics",
          "SmartEdit",
          "Store-Finder",
          "Personalization",
          "TMS-GTM",
          "TMS-AEPL",
          "Account",
          "Profile"
        ],
        "type": "string"
      },
```

Then, please notice that every feature here is mapped to a specific package from spartacus, to determine which package is required;
example, regarding to **cart:**

```
export const SPARTACUS_CART = '@spartacus/cart';
...
export const CLI_CART_SAVED_CART_FEATURE = 'Saved-Cart';

export const CLI_CART_QUICK_ORDER_FEATURE = 'Quick-Order';

....
[SPARTACUS_CART]: [CLI_CART_SAVED_CART_FEATURE, CLI_CART_QUICK_ORDER_FEATURE],
```

This means that if you include either *"Saved-Cart"* or *"Quick-Order"*, you will have `@spartacus/cart` package in your `package.json` . Does this make sense?

I think *Wishlist* is not a feature package, but it's embedded somehow in the core (a module with a component and so). And B2b is put as a module, and something depending on which specific features are included (it seems like if *"Administration"* feature would have some relationship, but not sure, see the code below)

```
      shouldAddFeature(
        CLI_ORGANIZATION_ADMINISTRATION_FEATURE,
        options.features
      )
        ? chain([
            addAdministrationFeature(options),
            configureB2bFeatures(options, packageJson),
          ])
        : noop(),
```

I think this context would serve as a guide for you. Please let me know.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing `@spartacus/schematics` has the latest version `4.3.x`, which contains the features Cart, B2B Checkout, Wishlist and Scheduled Replenishment embedded in the core libraries (`@spartacus/core` and `@spartacus/storefront`). In other words, you cannot opt-in to them with a schematics flag - you just have them anyway.

Since 5.0, [the Spartacus team plans](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/spartacus-roadmap/#50-scheduled-for-q4-2022) to move those features to separate, optional libraries. Then you'll be able to pick them with appropriate schematics flags like `--features=Wishlist` etc.